# Array slicing between different types in Ada

Tags: arrays, ada

[An Ada tutorial I'm reading](http://www.adahome.com/ammo/cpp2ada.html#1.1.6) says that this is a valid thing to do in Ada:

```
Large : array (0 .. 100) of Integer;
Small : array (0 .. 3) of Integer;

-- extract section from one array into another.
Small(0 .. 3) := Large(10 .. 13);
```

[However, when I actually try it](https://ideone.com/5AA3pC), it doesn't work.

I'm using ideone's online Ada environment to play with this stuff, for simplicity (link above). Is the tutorial wrong, or is it referring to a version of Ada which ideone doesn't implement?

Comment: Could someone provide a link to a better tutorial?

Comment: The tutorial is wrong on this point.  Maybe it's a good tutorial other than that, I don't know.  Unfortunately, I don't think adahome.com is being maintained any more and probably hasn't been for a while, and it looks like it covers only Ada 95 although we've had two new standards since then.

Comment: [Ada 95: The Craft of Object-Oriented Programming](http://archive.adaic.com/docs/craft/craft.html) is good. Note the warning about broken links, though! There’s a good set of links on the [parent page](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/).

Comment: Good Lord, stay off adahome! That is a derelict site that does nothing but damage the perception of Ada. Its owner will neither take the unmaintained site down nor relinquish the domain name (offers have been made in the past to buy it from him). A pox on him!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial is wrong.

This will compile, though:

```
type Integer_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Integer;
Large : Integer_Array (0 .. 100);
Small : Integer_Array (0 .. 3);

...
Small (0 .. 3) := Large (10 .. 13);
```

The details: In my example, `Integer_Array` is a **type** (actually a type and a "first subtype"), and `Integer_Array(0..100)` and `Integer_Array(0..3)` are constrained **subtypes**.    Array types in Ada specify the type(s) of the index(es) and the type of the element, but not the bounds; bounds are specified by subtypes, specifically constrained subtypes.  (That doesn't mean that you need a `subtype` declaration; a `type` declaration can cause both a type and a constrained subtype to be defined.)

An Ada assignment requires (usually) that the source and destination be of the same type, but they can be different subtypes.  So in my example, both the source and destination are subtypes of `Integer_Array`, and therefore the assignment meets this requirement.

In the original example, the declarations of `Large` and `Small` define new **anonymous** array types.  Each type is unbounded, and the declarations also define bounded subtypes that are used as the variables' subtypes.  But the important thing here is that two distinct types are defined, and you can't assign one type to the other.  Furthermore, since the types are unnamed, you can't use a type conversion to make the assignment work, as you could in an example like this:

```
type Integer_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Integer;
Large : array (0 .. 100) of Integer;
Small : Integer_Array (0 .. 3);

...
Small (0 .. 3) := Integer_Array (Large (10 .. 13));
```

Here, `Large` and `Small` again have two distinct types, but a type conversion is possible because the destination type is named.

The moral here is that it's better to use named array types.  Variable declarations like

```
Large : array (0 .. 100) of Integer;
```

can be good enough in some instances; but as this example shows, there are certain things you can't do with them.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. Thanks for the clarification, though. I am assume that the same magic (which I haven't investigated yet) is why I can do `Large := Large(0..10) & Large(11..100);`; the slicing and the `&` operator produce subtypes of Large, which are assignment-compatible to Large if the bounds match?

Comment: @DavidGiven Right, because in that case only one anonymous type is involved.